# dplyr verbs removing custom classes and attributes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a package that relies on adding a class and attributes to a data frame, and would like to be able to use `dplyr` verbs with it.

The only trouble is they seem to strip away the classes and attributes that I've added to my data frames.

**Example**

```
class(mtcars) <- c("new_class", class(mtcars))
attr(mtcars, "foo") <- "bar"
```

Examining the structure shows that mtcars now includes the new class and attributes

```
> mtcars %>% str
Classes ‘new_class’, ‘new_class’ and 'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 - attr(*, "foo")= chr "bar"
```

But when I use `filter`, it seems to lose the classes and attributes.

```
> mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 8) %>% str
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  18.7 14.3 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 15.5 15.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ disp: num  360 360 276 276 276 ...
 $ hp  : num  175 245 180 180 180 205 215 230 150 150 ...
 $ drat: num  3.15 3.21 3.07 3.07 3.07 2.93 3 3.23 2.76 3.15 ...
 $ wt  : num  3.44 3.57 4.07 3.73 3.78 ...
 $ qsec: num  17 15.8 17.4 17.6 18 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ am  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ carb: num  2 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 2 2 ...
```

Is that behaviour expected?

What can I do to work around it?

Comment: [**This dplyr issue**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/719) seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks Henrik - this helped me quite a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` calls `filter_`, which uses the method for a `data.frame` (because there is no filter method for `new_class`. `filter_.data.frame` then uses calls the filter method for a `tbl_df` and uses `as.data.frame` to return a `data.frame`.

```
dplyr:::filter_.data.frame
## function (.data, ..., .dots) 
## {
##     dots <- lazyeval::all_dots(.dots, ..., all_named = TRUE)
##     as.data.frame(filter_(tbl_df(.data), .dots = dots))
## }
## <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

The coercion to `tbl_df` removes the extra class, but keeps the attribute `foo`.

```
mtcars %>% tbl_df %>% str
```

The filtering seems to loose the attribute `foo`.

```
mtcars %>% tbl_df %>% filter(cyl == 8) %>% str
```

Comment: Thanks Shadow. I was able to make a `filter` generic, define for method for my class, and define a default method that just points to `dplyr::filter`. Similar to this gist: https://gist.github.com/datalove/88f5a24758b2d8356e32